# Replacing Object in Array doesn't work, but Adding a new one Does

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have a function that is designed to take an object, and, if one with the same identifier string already exists in an array, update it, and if it doesn't, add the object. The adding part works, but for some reason the update functionality loses data.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)addOrUpdateGroup:(Object *)myObject
{
    for (H2Group *existingObject in objectsArray) {
        if ([existingObject.identifier isEqualToString:myObject.identifier]) {
            [objectsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[objectsArray indexOfObject:existingObject] withObject:myObject];
            return;
        }
    }
    [objectsArray addObject:myObject];    
}
```

When calling this method with an object that has a counterpart in the array, it executes, but does not seem to replace the object.

Using breakpoints and logs, I have ascertained that:

- The loop is entered, and the detection of a new object with an existing identifier works fine.
- The new object is intact and if I instead use `[objectsArray addObject:myObject]`, the object is added properly.
- The same problem occurs if I use `replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:myObject`.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: 1) I'm surprised this code doesn't crash since you are modifying a mutable array while you use fast enumeration with it. 2) This code is very inefficient. Why use fast enumeration and `indexOfObject:`? Either use a normal `for` loop so you already know the index of the matching object or use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` to get the benefits of both.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think it's not crashing because the loop is broken by the return statement after the array is mutated and before the loop continues to another iteration. But I'll try your method too.

Comment: How are you determining that the array isn't properly updated when `replaceObjectAtIndex:` is being called?

Comment: I'm adding breakpoints before and after that allow me to inspect myObject as well as the contents of objectsArray.

Comment: I suspect the code is working fine and the problem is with your determination that it isn't working. I'd suggest writing a proper `description` method for your `Object` class so that it shows enough info to clearly differentiate each instance and then log `objectsArray` before and after calling `addOrUpdateGroup:`. Then make sure there is a difference in the log output. Or perhaps the problem is simply that `existingObject` and `myObject` are actually the same object instance or they have the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is more efficient, safer, and (in my opinion) more readable:

```
- (void)addOrUpdateGroup:(Object *)myObject {
    NSUInteger idx = [objectsArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(Object *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [object.identifier isEqualToString:myObject.identifier];
    }];

    if (idx != NSNotFound) {
        [objectsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:myObject];
    } else {
        [objectsArray addObject:myObject];    
    }
}
```

It presupposes that `objectsArray` contains only `Object`s.

Comment: Thanks for the more efficient solution, I wasn't aware of this method. However, the bug is still present — the new object is neither replaced nor added. Clearly, the issue is with the replaceObjectAtIndex method call.